# how to format data I send to API

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, markup

I send data to API (user submits form and it's sent to the API).
I need every field on a new row.
`\n` and `<br>` inside the string does not work
so help me to format
[image]

I need such output as :

`Имя: ${username}`

`Сообщение: ${comment}`

`Номер тел: ${phone}`

every one on a new row

Comment: Where do you output the data? Sending it to an API is one thing, but displaying is another thing. As you are asking about outputting the data in separate lines, please show us the code you use to the data you sent to the api.

Comment: `Имя: ${username}\nСообщение: ${comment}\nНомер тел: ${phone}`

Answer (score 0):

In template strings you can write a line break and it should be retained.

```
bodyMessage = `Имя: ${username}

Сообщение: ${comment}

Номер тел: ${phone}`
```

Should work

Or if you only want one line break do it like htis

```
bodyMessage = `Имя: ${username}
Сообщение: ${comment}
Номер тел: ${phone}`
```

Comment: This will add aditional spaces and new lines

Comment: @Adarsh Mohan Fixed it.

Comment: Still you will get additional spaces and extra new lines

Comment: This is the format that is displayed in the question, but I will add one without the extra line as well.

Comment: even if you remove the extra lines, it will still have many spaces before `Сообщение` and `Номер тел`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\n` for new lines

```js
var username = 'username'
var comment = 'comment'
var phone = 'phone'


var bodyMessage = `Имя: ${username}\nСообщение: ${comment}\nНомер тел: ${phone}`

console.log(bodyMessage)
```